# how to select fields from joined table properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Here are my simplified models, I have joined models:

```rb
class Apartment < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :towers
end
```

and

```rb
class Tower < ApplicationRecord
  belong_to :apartment
end
```

and then I tried to join both tables in controller. I also tried it in rails console like this :

```
Apartment.joins(:towers).select('apartments.id', 'apartments.name', 'towers.id' , 'towers.name')
```

the problem is above query only returns

> apartments.id and apartments.name

also tried to use alias like this, still no luck

```
Apartment.joins(:towers).select('apartments.id', 'apartments.name',
'towers.id as towerid' , 'towers.name as towername')
```

I have confirmed that all towers have an apartment, I know i could do this to get 1 record

> Apartment.joins(:towers).select('apartments.id', 'apartments.name',
> 'towers.id' , 'towers.name').first.towers.id

and etc, but i need all records and all those fields, please advice.

here is the latest result i got in rails console :

```
 Apartment Load (1.0ms)  SELECT apartments.id, apartments.name, towers.id as towerid, towers.
    tower_name as towername FROM `apartments` INNER JOIN `towers` ON `towers`.`apt_id` = `
    apartments`.`id`
    => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Apartment id: 5, name: "basura">, #<Apartment id: 5, apt_
    name: "basura">, #<Apartment id: 124, name: "hydra">, #<Apartment id: 124, name: "hy
    dra">, #<Apartment id: 126, name: "mediterania">, #<Apartment id: 126, name: "mediterania">, #<Apartment id: 142, name: "apartement gajah mada">, #<Apartment id: 142, name: "apartement gajah mada">]>
```

as you can see, above query only return 2 fields, i need the result to be like this :

```
#<Apartment id: 126, name: "mediterania", tower_id: 12, tower_name: "tower A">, 
#<Apartment id: 126, name: "mediterania", tower_id: 15, tower_name: "tower F">
```

etcc...

Comment: use '*includes*' in place of '*joins*'

Comment: Just for your info. `first.towers.id` will not work You will have to write  `first.towers.first.id`

Comment: @GauravGupta tried to use includes in rails console, it throw an error "unknown column 'towers.tower_name'"

Comment: @HendraLim It will not work because towers is activerecord relation you have to do towers.first.name

Comment: @Dinesh would n't it only returns a single record? could you please put a complete example of your suggestion in answer section.

Comment: @HendraLim  It will not return single record because you have many `towers`. That's it.

Comment: @HendraLim My answer will get you the result you want. Also I have added explaination. I hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 26):

The only way I see this is possible is using `as`

```
q = Apartment.joins(:towers).select('apartments.id, apartments.name, towers.id as t_id, towers.name as t_name')

q.first.t_id
q.first.t_name
```

**Why first.towers.id will not work?**

`apartment.towers` will return `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`. You can think of it as a collection of towers. In SQL query you are referring to `towers` table. But when you run apartment.towers.id you are calling id on CollectionProxy  object which will not work. You can get first tower using `towers.first`.

Regarding,

```
Apt Load (1.0ms)  SELECT apts.id, apts.apt_name, towers.id as towerid, towers.
    tower_name as towername FROM `apts` INNER JOIN `towers` ON `towers`.`apt_id` = `
    apts`.`id`
    => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Apt id: 5, apt_name: "basura">, #<Apt id: 5, apt_
    name: "basura">, #<Apt id: 124, apt_name: "hydra">, #<Apt id: 124, apt_name: "hy
    dra">, #<Apt id: 126, apt_name: "mediterania">, #<Apt id: 126, apt_name: "mediterania">, #<Apt id: 142, apt_name: "apartement gajah mada">, #<Apt id: 142, apt_name: "apartement gajah mada">]>
```

**What you see in console is result returned by `inspsect` method. The `inspect` method is not designed to show non column attributes. Hence even if you have towername in memory it will only show attributes which are columns of Apartment model.**
More about  [inspect](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-inspect)

I also recommend to try following:

```
Apartment.joins(:towers).pluck('apartments.id, apartments.name, towers.id as t_id, towers.name as t_name')
```

Above statement will get all data in array. The same result you get with select but select will not load all data in array.

Comment: indeed it return tower name, but the problem it only return 1 record, what i need is to return data like this <Apt id: 126, apt_name: "mediterania", t_id: 12, t_name: "tower A">, #<Apt id: 126, apt_name: "mediterania", t_id:13, t_name: "tower B"> etc etc.

Comment: @HendraLim You have it just like you want. In console it will show only columns which are present in Apt Model.

Comment: i have used pluck before, but since it return an array instead of an ORM object, it does not solve my problem, btw i have solved my problem, i guess you are right i still can access tower name and id field,  even though it s not showing in console, upvoted, thanks for help.

Answer (score 12):

You should use

```
Apartment.joins(:towers).select('apartments.id, apartments.name, towers.id , towers.name')
```

that is all column names inside a single string.

[Refer this.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields)

Comment: can you post the generated sql query ? Or If you are trying in console, just add `.to_sql` at the end and see if it is generating correct query.

Comment: here you go : => "SELECT apts.id, apts.apt_name, towers.id, tower.tower_name FROM `apts` INNER
 JOIN `towers` ON `towers`.`apt_id` = `apts`.`id`"

Comment: this is kinda strange, because i can see the query is generated correctly, but somehow the query result did not reflect it. oh btw, i also tried to check  generated query with my first approach, all field in separated string, it also return the same query as your approach.

Comment: yes, its strange. BTW did you edited the result and replaced `apartments` to `apts` or your table name is like that ? And can you run this query directly through mysql console or any GUI like `phpMyAdmin` if you have and see if it returns the result correctly.

Comment: actually my real model named apts, but in order to make it more understandable so i wrote it as apartments, i did run the generated query in my sql workbench, and the result is exactly what i need, but somehow it did not work in rails.

Comment: So what exactly Rails return if you run the my posted query ?

Comment: i updated my question with query result which i run from rails console, i can see the generated query also with alias that i added, but still it only returns apt_id and apt_name.

Comment: @HendraLim As I have described in my answer you have to use alias to get the particular attribute. You have what you want, it just that it is not getting shown in console.

Comment: @sajan i have solved the problem, there is nothing wrong with our's initial approach, its just those fields are not showing in console (tower.id, tower.name), but those fields are there, and can be used directly, many thanks, upvoted.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out from my end too, it shows only the original model name and data. not the joined model. Feel free to mark any answer as accepted , that will render that you found a solution and not an unanswered question.

Comment: This works! It does return all the fields, but it shows only the "Apparment" in the console. `.as_json` will show you everything is included!

Answer (score 6):

Rails 7.1 [adds](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/45612) support for such queries, now `select` accepts hash

You can use aliases like this

```
Apartment
  .joins(:towers)
  .select(
    apartments: { id: :apartment_id, name: :apartment_name },
    towers: { id: :tower_id, name: :tower_name }
  )
```

It produces such query

```sql
SELECT apartments.id AS apartment_id, apartments.name AS apartments_name,
  towers.id AS tower_id, towers.name AS tower_name
FROM apartments
INNER JOIN towers ON towers.apartment_id = apartments.id
```

Comment: I tried this (as I prefer to use hashes than strings for queries) but received this error: `Unsupported argument type: Hash. Construct an Arel node instead.`

Comment: That is only supported in Rails 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the alias names like below

```
Apartment.joins(:towers).select('apartments.id as apartment_id, apartments.name as apartment_name, towers.id as tower_id , towers.name as tower_name)
```

Comment: Try this. Apartment.joins("OUTER JOIN towers on towers.apartment_id = apartments.id").select('apartments.id as apartment_id, apartments.name as apartment_name, towers.id as tower_id , towers.name as tower_name)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Apartment.joins(:towers).select('apartments.id as id, apartments.name as apartment_name, towers.id as tower_id , towers.name as tower_name)

you will get the response like this
#ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Apt id: 126, apt_name: "mediterania", tower_id: 12, tower_name: "tower A">,
#<Apt id: 126, apt_name: "mediterania", tower_id: 15, tower_name: "tower F">]>